# ArcGIS Javascript API edit data programmatically

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a form that auto generates a unique number. I want to update/edit an attribute with this number. Is this possible using one of the Esri editing widgets? Attribute Inspector, Editing widget or Template Picker etc...or would this be easier to implement with an applyEdits() call?

All the user needs to do is drop a point on the map. The only attribute besides the Esri objectId will be this form generated number. Wondering how to tie this auto generated form number to an attribute on the point automatically so that the user does not need to manually edit the attribute.

Comment: it would help if you could edit this question to include more details. For example, please outline the workflow. How is the form populated? How does the form relate to the features on the map? Can you tell us more about your application - is it based on any templates, or have you built it yourself, etc. At the moment this question is quite broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FeatureLayer's [before-apply-edits event](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#event-before-apply-edits) could be handled to populate the attribute of each graphic in the `adds` array.